# where should pubspec and how many with multiple apps

Tags: dart

Suppose there is a need for a *project* with 3 libraries and 2 apps. From the pub documentation I'm choosing a structure like below. The apps are different enough, though, that it is desirable they have their own directory. The documentation at (http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/#adding-a-dependency) says to put a *pubspec.yaml* file at the *top-level*. Is the *top-level* in the context below the *project* folder?

If there is one pubspec and it is at the */project* level and shared with the libs, wouldn't that mean users of any of the libs only but not the apps would unnecessarily require extra packages (like good_stuff and big_stuff)?

```
/project
    /app
        /app1    (uses l1, package:good_stuff)
        /app2    (uses l1, l2, l3, package:big_stuff)
    /lib
        /l1
        /l2      (uses package:pathos/path.dart)
        /l3      (uses l1 and l2)
        /src
            /l1
            /l2
            /l3
```

So, given this desired setup, how many pubspec's and where would be created to satisfy these dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Packages

You should put your `pubspec.yaml` file in the top level of your **package**. In Pub, a package is the largest unit of self-contained code, and contains all the libraries, executables, examples, documentation, tests, and tools required for the package to live by itself.

In Pub, there are loosely two types of packages:

- **Library packages**, are effectively just a library in the conventional sense, and are intended to be used by other packages.
- **Application packages** are consumers of other packages and define an application that you can run on the command line, server, web, or elsewhere.

These are loose definitions because library packages might have executables, and application packages might have some reusable libraries that are useful in other applications.

Generally, you want to try to make your project out of several discrete components, which can change and be re-used individually. This is in contrast to making one package for all parts of the application.

#### Your Project

I would recommend you have the following structure:

```
/project
  /app1
    - pubspec.yaml
  /app2
    - pubspec.yaml
  /mechanics
    - pubspec.yaml
    /lib
      l1.dart
      l2.dart
      l3.dart
      /src
        ...
```

Here you'd have 2 application packages and one library package.

A few notes:

- you can refer to the `mechanics` package with [path dependencies](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/dependencies.html#path-packages)
- you only really want `project/` as the top top level if you're anticipating keeping this whole project bundled together (say if you're selling it.) If you anticipate `app1` and `app2` living separately, you don't need `project/` at all.
- you can totally make `l1`, `l2`, and `l3` their own packages if you feel that they can live well enough separately. In that case, just make them all their own package.

#### See also:

- [Creating a Package](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/#creating-a-package)
- [Package Layout](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html)